# How can I custom-align cells in a table?

Tags: tables, align, pgfplotstable

I want to read a table from a file, where each cell contains two numbers separated by a $\pm$ operator. I want the cells be aligned at the $\pm$ operator. My current code can read the table successfully, but the $\pm$ are not aligned.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata}
    Types,First Col,Second Col,Third Col
    TypeA,-0.1575 $\pm$ 0.0118,-0.2428 $\pm$ 0.0074,-0.1457 $\pm$ 0.0078
    TypeB, 0.0074 $\pm$ 0.0308,-0.276  $\pm$ 0.0251,-0.0181 $\pm$ 0.00173
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    column type=l,
    string type,
    every head row/.style={
        after row={
            \midrule
        },
     },
     every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
     display columns/0/.style={column type = {l|}},
     display columns/1/.style={column type = {c|}},
     display columns/2/.style={column type = {c|}},
     display columns/3/.style={column type = {c}},
]{mydata}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered `siunitx` and its column styles?

Comment: I tried but couldn't get it work. Does siunitx work for non-numeric values (since 0.24 $\pm$ 0.04 is interpreted as a string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was painful!

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
  uncertainty-separator={\pm},
  table-figures-uncertainty=1,
  table-number-alignment=center,
  table-figures-decimal=5,% reserve space for 5 decimal places
  output-open-uncertainty={},% prevents surrounding uncertainty with (...)
  output-close-uncertainty={}}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata}
    Types,First Col,Second Col,Third Col
    TypeA,-0.1575 $\pm$ 0.0118,-0.2428 $\pm$ 0.0074,-0.1457 $\pm$ 0.0078
    TypeB, 0.0074 $\pm$ 0.0308,-0.276  $\pm$ 0.0251,-0.0181 $\pm$ 0.00173
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    ignore chars={\$},% siunitx does not like $\pm$, but \pm is fine
    string type,
    %multicolumn names={l|},% do not apply S format to header
    display columns/0/.style={column type = {l|}},
    display columns/1/.style={column type = {S|},column name={\multicolumn{1}{l|}{First Col}}},
    display columns/2/.style={column type = {S|},column name={\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Second Col}}},
    display columns/3/.style={column type = {S},column name={\multicolumn{1}{l}{Third Col}}},
    every head row/.style={
        before row={\toprule},
        after row={\midrule},
     },
     every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{mydata}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: +1! Only a little thing: I think the vertical rule at the end of the table should be removed...

Comment: I don't know how you figured it out, but that's brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: I think your last comment is for @alguru...