# How to represent two excel columns mean and standard deviation as single column as mean±standard deviation in latex?

Tags: tables

I have two columns with multiple rows, one column contains mean and second column contains standard deviation. I want to represent both columns as single column as mean ± standard deviation in latex without writing it manually for each row in latex.

Comment: I take it the data is in a csv file, so you probably should use pgfplotstable to read the file.  If the data is in two columns, just throw a $\pm$ between the columns.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354793/how-can-i-custom-align-cells-in-a-table as a related but more difficult problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but not able to resolve the issue.. how both columns will be merged and how it will fetch data from excel. For converting excel data to latex code, I am using a plugin but it also didn't help.....

Comment: If you have something that already converts your excel data to LaTeX, you shoud show us what you have so far in a MWE, that way we'd know where to start.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo ... I got the clue from your comment and link....

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
If reading whole table:

\csvautotabular{a.csv} \\

If fetching in the modified form: 

\csvreader[tabular=|l|c|c|,
table head=\hline Name & Mean\_Std\\\hline,
late after line=\\\hline]%
{a.csv}{n=\name,mean=\m,std=\s}%
{\name & \m$\pm$\s}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was thinking more like \csvreader[tabular=|l|c@{$\pm$}c|

Comment: Ya, it's also a viable alternative....